# Unchecked checkbox returns null when using getParameter

Tags: java, checkbox, struts2, jsp-tags

I have a jsp page which have check boxes `<s:checkbox name="mt"/>` and I am getting values using `String y = getParameter("mt");` in my action class.

I got `y="false"` if the checkbox is unchecked but I upgrade my jars from struts 2.3 to struts 2.5.10 after that I am getting null in y when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Have you added value for it ?

Comment: No, I check the issue once again and issue is because I implement ParameterAware interface and override the setParameter method after the struts jar upgrade this interface is depreciated and need to use HttpParametersAware  thanks

Comment: Okay nice. +1 from me for question

Comment: You don't have to use `getParameter` at all.

Comment: Did you try String[] mtValues = request.getParameterValues("mt");